# How does this proof on constrained extrema even work?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

In class, we were looking for extrema $\hat{y}$ of functional $\mathcal{L}$, while demanding that $\Phi(\hat{y}) = l$ for some other functional $\Phi$.

My professor proved the following statement: If the bounded extrema of functional $\mathcal{L}$ is obtained at point $\hat{y}(x) \in M$, then we have: $\ker (D_{\hat{y}} \Phi) \subset \ker ( D_{\hat{y}} \mathcal{L} ).$ The proof went as follows.

Let $v = v(x,t): [a,b] \times (- \varepsilon, \varepsilon) \to U$ be a path of functions $[a,b]\to U$, where $U$ is a Banach space, such that $v(x,0) = \hat{y}(x)$. Furthermore, let $v(x,t)$ lie entirely in $\Phi^{-1} =: M$. This means that $\Phi(v(x,t)) = l$. We can take the derivative with respect to time to obtain $ \frac{d}{dt} \big|_{t=0} \Phi(v(x,t)) = (D_{\hat{y}(x)} \Phi)(\dot{v}) = 0. $ This is true for $\dot{v}(x) = \frac{d}{dt} \big|_{t=0} v(x,t)$ of any path $t \mapsto v(x,t)$ in $M$ that foes through $\hat{y}(x)$. Therefore: $\dot{v} \in \ker D_{\hat{y}(x)} \Phi$ for any such path.

Now let's take a look at derivative of a composite function: $t \mapsto \mathcal{L}(v(x,t))$. We obtain $ \frac{d}{dt} \big|_{t=0} \mathcal{L}(v(x,t)) = 0 $, where $v(x,0) = \hat{y}(x)$ is an extrema. Therefore $(D_{\hat{y}(x)} \mathcal{L})(\dot{v}) = 0$. We saw that $\dot{v} \in \ker D_{\hat{y}(x)} \Phi$ and by what we wrote above, it is also true that $(D_{\hat{y}(x)} \mathcal{L})(\dot{v}) = 0 \Rightarrow \dot{v} \in \ker D_{\hat{y}(x)} \mathcal{L}$

QED

I am absolutely confused as to how this proof works. Instead of choosing any element in $\ker (D_{\hat{y}} \Phi) $ and showing that it is also in $\ker ( D_{\hat{y}} \mathcal{L} )$, we just looked at paths that go through $\hat{y}(x)$ and showed that they are in both kernels. What am I missing? How is that enough?

Answer (score 1):

The proof aims to show that if y^(x) is a bounded extrema of functional L, then the kernel of Dy^Φ is contained in the kernel of Dy^L. The starting point of the proof is to consider a path v(x,t) that lies in M and passes through y^(x) at t=0. By definition, the derivative of Φ with respect to time at t=0 is zero along this path, which means that v˙(x) lies in the kernel of Dy^Φ. Next, the derivative of the composite function t↦L(v(x,t)) is calculated at t=0 and shown to be zero, implying that v˙(x) also lies in the kernel of Dy^L. Hence, it is concluded that the kernel of Dy^Φ is contained in the kernel of Dy^L. The reason this is enough to conclude that the kernel of Dy^Φ is contained in the kernel of Dy^L is because the kernel of a linear operator is a linear subspace, and it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. Hence, if a point v˙(x) lies in the kernel of Dy^Φ and is also in the kernel of Dy^L, then it follows that any linear combination of such points will also lie in the kernel of both Dy^Φ and Dy^L. In conclusion, the proof you mentioned shows that if y^(x) is a bounded extrema of functional L, then any element in the kernel of Dy^Φ will also be in the kernel of Dy^L.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $v(x,t)$ lies entirely in $\Phi^{-1}(l)$ implies that its tangent vector is in $ker(D_{\hat{y}}\Phi)$. This comes from a standard characterization of the tangent space of the inverse image. Your professor is using a definition of tangent space that implies that all tangent vectors come as the tangent vectors to paths. So this part of the argument adresses your question.

Comment: I still don't understand the argument. Are you saying that the only vectors $w$ for which $D_{\hat{y}} \Phi w = 0$ are those for which there exists a path entirely in $\Phi^{-1} (l)$ such that $ w = \dot{v}$? If so, why is that true? And even if it is, why on earth did we have to check that $D_{\hat{y}} \Phi \dot{v} = 0$? I'm sorry, but I'm 100% confused and have no idea how to proceed here.

Comment: You don’t understand the argument because you are missing the definition of tangent vector. Ask in class.

Comment: My classes are over, I am now studying for the exam. If you know what's going on, I don't understand why it's so hard to try to explain or at least clearly point out what I'm missing?

Comment: Mathew ok. In any setting there is a theorem that says all tangent vectors arise as tangents to curves. I don’t know the framework that your professor was working in so I can’t give you a cogent proof. I can tell from what you wrote that you don’t understand this.

Comment: I'm not sure if you see what confuses me. So let's ssy that $\ker D_{\hat{y}} \Phi$ is the tangent space of $M$ at $\hat{y}$ and that all the vectors in this space come as derivatives of paths of $M$. Why on earth did we show that derivatives of paths lie in  $\ker D_{\hat{y}} \Phi$ then? Is that first half absolutely unnecessary? Shouldn't we just take such a path and show that its derivative is in $\ker D_{\hat{y}} \mathcal{L}$ ???

Comment: What is the derivative of a constant function?

Comment: It's just zero. I don,'t know what youre trying to say